# C++ type comparison

Tags: c++, arduino, type-conversion

I have a String ....

```
String msg;
```

This variable might contain text or a two digit control code.  The text can be up to fifty char.  The control code will begin with special character like "$", or "#" and some other character (or two).

So why cant I test for the control code with something like ....

```
if (msg[0] == "$") ....
```

I get an error reporting that "**ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer**"  Sorry, but I don't know what that is telling me.  I thought this would be a comparison between a char and a char. 
I've not worked with c++ Strings so I must admit total ignorance.
(This is in the Arduino IDE if that makes a difference)

Comment: This type of problem would have been avoided completely by simply reading a basic introductory text, rather than relying on guesswork.   Most basic introductory material covers the concepts of strings, characters, and how to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quotes in C++ specify a null terminated C-string. Use single quotes instead:

```
if (msg[0] == '$') ....
```